# Dúvida sobre domínios

Tags: aplicação-web

Estou com a seguinte dúvida. Tenho um painel de controle onde o usuário consegue adicionar diversas informações em seu site, porém, o site do usuário fica em meu domínio como por exemplo `www.meudominio.com/sitedousuario1` como eu poderia exibir esse conteúdo no domínio do cliente `sidedousuario1`, `sitedousuario2` ? Se a pergunta for um pouco complexa, apenas me mostrem um caminho.

Comment: É tipo um shopping virtual onde cada cliente tem sua loja dentro dentro do meu domínio? Se for o caso eu forneço uma página em PHP de controle para os clientes e essa página consome um script python que está ligado a um banco dados próprio contendo somente as configurações de cada cliente.

Comment: Tudo bem, mas e o domínio ?

Comment: Mas o domínio o usuário compra e aponta para o meu servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma estratégia parecida com o heroku.

Eles utilizam o padrão de utilizar o site do cliente como um subdomínio do domínio deles.

Sempre quando você acessa é algo como: `exemplo.herokuapp.com`

Desta forma para cada cliente você pode ter um subdomínio e mesmo assim possuir apenas 1 certificado, visto que eles utilizam `wildcards` certificados, que valem para todos os subdomínios.

A diferença para o que você descreveu é que os subdomínios serão:

```
siteusuario1.meudominio.com
siteusuario2.meudominio.com
```

Essa é a minha contribuição mas não sei pode onde começar.

Answer (score -2):

Você tem que registrar um domínio próprio pro seu cliente (assim como você fez pra você), e contratar um serviço de hospedagem, publicar os DNS e enviar o sistema pro servidor do seu cliente. Basicamente o que você fez pra você mesmo.

Comment: mas isto, seria inviável para mim.

Comment: Imagina isto para 100 clientes

Comment: Me explica melhor o tipo de serviço que você fornece pro seu cliente. Eu tenho um sistema próprio (desenvolvido e projetado por mim), quando consigo um novo cliente, eu faço toda a configuração básica pra ele: registro de dominio e hospedagem. Depois instalo minha aplicação e ele faz uso no dominio proprio.

Comment: Eu tenho um serviço onde todos os meus clientes estão em um único banco de dados, porém é inviável para mim, ficar registrando domínio para cada cliente, já que isso é da parte dele.

Comment: Existe um apontamento que o cliente pode fazer no painel de controle dele. pra ter o domínio dele funcionando no seu "sub domínio". Mas infelizmente não sei como funciona. Quem quem usa desse artificio é a plataforma do blogspot. Ja apontei diversos domínios pra plataforma do google. Eles tem um passo-a-passo ... mas nao sei como o servidor deles faz esse tratamento.